# Add author affiliation to Microsoft Academic evaluate API request

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-academic-graph

I have a Python function for calling the Microsoft Academic API [evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-evaluate-method) method. The function currently takes in the author name and returns citation count:

```
import requests

def get_author_CC(subscription_key, author_name):
    url = 'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate'
    params = {
        "expr": f"Composite(AA.AuN=='{author_name}')",
        "attributes": "ECC,CC",
        'count': 10000
    }
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}

    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json().get('entities')
    
    return sum([ld.get('ECC') for ld in r])
```

Since I know the affiliation of several of the authors I am interested in querying for, I would like to add the [affiliation parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-entity-attributes) to the request. However, I am not quite understanding how to go about doing that. I have tried this:

```
import requests

def get_author_CC(subscription_key, author_name, affiliation):
    url = 'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate'
    params = {
        "expr": f"Composite(AA.AuN=='{author_name}', Ty==5, AfN=='{affiliation}')",
        "attributes": "ECC,CC",
        'count': 10000
    }
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}

    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json().get('entities')
    
    return sum([ld.get('ECC') for ld in r])
```

but that returned errors, so obviously that wasn't quite right.

As an example, one author I am looking at is laurens van der maaten who has about 40,000+ citation counts and is affiliated with Facebook. So the new function should still return 40,000+ citation counts but use the fact that she was at Facebook to narrow the search (especially useful for more common names).

Any help here is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the query expression syntax page in the [MAG docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-query-expression-syntax); they cover this specific example. Format should look like:

```
Composite(And(AA.AuN='mike smith',AA.AfN='harvard university'))
```